# When to use socket.io?

Tags: web-services, node.js, network-programming, socket.io

I am learning NodeJS and was able to make a server and an iPhone app that issues an HTTP GET request to the server and retrieve a JSON string from it. I didn't need to use socket.io for this. So why would I need to use it?

Comment: When you need more general socket communication?

Comment: So if you're receiving JSON data from the server, you don't need it? What about for sending it to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just pulling JSON from the server your solution works fine.  However suppose you want to push data from the server back to the client. Socket.io is a very elegant solution for doing this.  Firstly because it handles the push side and secondly because it handles browser degradation gracefully as the 'jQuery of sockets'

Comment: It's required for pushing the same kind of data back to the server?

Comment: It's not required you could use WebSockets/Comet directly but it is a much more elegant solution. Also my answer was in reference to pushing from the server to the client, not the client to the server.

Comment: Why do sockets have to be used at all? They weren't used to get data from the server.

Comment: As a thought experiment how would you design a web application that pushes 'Hello world' from the server to the client at a random interval.  It should be push based in other words if the interval is 5 minutes the client should not be polling the server every few seconds.  That is why you need sockets.

Comment: So sockets aren't required for the client to send data to the server?